# Minimal CPU and memory usage during concatenation, future advice need

Tags: cpu, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm joining two 4K Prores422 HQ MOV files, a short spot (1GB) and a feature film (220GB).

My current fps is around 9.0 and according to activity monitor my CPU usage is at 0.34% and only 5GB memory is used.

My current setup: iMac Pro with 2,3GHz 18 cores, 64GB RAM with a Radeon Pro Vega 64 GPU.

I choose ffmpeg for this task because I didn't want to reencode the footages. I realized that it does reencode them and it's doing it painfully slow. My 2015 Macbook Pro with mid specs produces the same speed.

Could someone give me some advice on how to speed up ffmpeg tasks like this one in the future? Or what could have been the quicker way to do it?

Comment: Share your full command and log.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7wqxXPRA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg is not re-encoding the files.

Your output speed is 0.382 with average output bitrate being 631679.5kbits/s, so around 30MB/s, which indicates disk I/O limitation. Your drive is probably SATA 3G/s and I see similar throughput on such interfaces.

Comment: Indeed, the input and output files are on a USB3 4TB external HDD.